# Inserir controller na aplicação apartir do template solicitado

Tags: angularjs, mvc

Estou criando uma aplicação angular onde, na página inicial eu ultilizo um controller para fazer algumas validações antes de proceder com o login da aplicação. Minha dúvida é, eu tenho como "instanciar" os controladores de cada template somente quando eu requisitar aquele template? Pergunto isso porque não quero ter 1 arquivo controllers com todos os controladores porque é ilógico no padrão de desenvolvimento MVC e sem contar que atrasa na inicialização da aplicação. Colocando em um rascunho ("chutando") creio que seria algo do tipo:

**Template :** página de cadastro

```
<script src="js/controllers/CadastroCtrl.js"></script>
<ion-view view-title="Cadastro" ng-controller="CadastroCtrl">
    <ion-content>
        <h1>Cadastre alguma coisa</h1>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Template :** página de listagem

```
<script src="js/controllers/ListagemCtrl.js"></script>
<ion-view view-title="Listagem" ng-controller="ListagemCtrl">
    <ion-content>
        <h1>Liste alguma coisa que foi cadastrada no outro template</h1>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Seria isso mesmo? Alguém tem alguma solução melhor para tratar as dependências de cada template? Eu dei o exemplo do controlador mas caso eu tenha também como dependência algum serviço (factory) ou algo do tipo também cairia nessa questão...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você precisa é usar um framework que gerencia suas dependências. Assim você consegue separar cada controller, service, directive, em arquivos separados, e gerenciá-los para que sejam carregados apenas quando necessário.

Dê uma olhada em [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

Para exemplo de como o código funciona, veja o [github](https://github.com/robsonflorentino/core-application) de um amigo.

Comment: certíssimo parceiro, eu já tinha chegado nessa solução do RequireJS e já estou usando ela algum tempo, só que esqueci de solucionar a pergunta rsrsrs, mas obrigado.