# Ajuda pagina Single Page Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Tenho uma aplicação com dividida em vários blocos de serviços desenvolvido utilizando NodeJs, AngularJs e MongoDB utilizando Express. Cada bloco de serviços tem seus próprios services, controllers e suas devidas partials que funcionam de forma independente, mas não consigo fazer link entre as diversas páginas para unificar a apresentação destes serviços. 
Preciso de ajuda para resolver este problema.

Comment: Podes explicar melhor como é a estrutura da tua aplicaçäo? e que código tens?

Comment: Você precisa criar módulos e atribuir esses blocos de services e controllers a eles. Olhe essa [outra resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64169/inserir-controller-na-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-apartir-do-template-solicitado/70658#70658) pra você ter uma idéia.